# Char and Varchar2 Columns showing Larger size in View

Tags: oracle, view, varchar2

I have a table like:

```
Table
{
...
...
SETTLEMENTDAY                          VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)  
ACCOUNT                                VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)  
AMOUNT                                 NUMBER(38,5)       
CURRENCY                               VARCHAR2(3 CHAR)   
...
...
}
```

When I am creating View using this table I am getting the following:

```
 View
    {
    ...
    ...
    SETTLEMENTDAY                          VARCHAR2(40 CHAR)  
    ACCOUNT                                VARCHAR2(200 CHAR)  
    AMOUNT                                 NUMBER(38,5)       
    CURRENCY                               VARCHAR2(12 CHAR)   
    ...
    ...
    }
```

There is no casting. 
I am using Oracle 12.2.0.1.0.
I tried to use following alter query but not helping

```
alter session set nls_length_semantics=CHAR;
```

I am not able to understand why the size is getting multiplied by 4. Which variable in database could have affected that.

Thanks,

Comment: How are you creating a view? I tried CVAS (Create View  As Select) from the table, and - no change in datatype.

Comment: I am also using CVAS. This view and tables are part of large scripts so something in scripts is off which is causing this behavior.

Comment: How are you "getting the following"? Are you using the `DESCRIBE` command? Using `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`? Or something else? "I am getting the following" is not a technical description of your action. Tell us where you get that info for both the table and the view.

Comment: using DESCRIBE.

Comment: It might depend on the database's default character set.  try `select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET'`